# PHP function for horizontal Woocommerce thumbnails and badges

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, css, html

I am looking for a PHP-function which checks if the product thumbnail is a specific size (in this case horizontal layout). If so, it should display the Woocommerce-badges (New, Sale, Featured ...) on a different height as the vertical thumbnails (with CSS). I don't know exactly how to start and would appreciate any answers.
[image: Here you can see what bugs me. I want the "NEW" badge to display for horizontal pictures also in left corner without changing the position for the vertical pictures.]

Comment: I don't know WooCommerce so I don't know what that template would be, but the image size metadata will be available in the loop where you're generating it. I assume that's in a containing div? I'd test the image dimensions at the point you generate the div, and add an extra class to the div if it's horizontal. Then you can do the rearrangement in CSS as you said. What's the function that the template calls to render the image?

Comment: @Rup thx for your comment. I've also thought about adding some kind of div but I really have no Idea how to add it to the image. As far as I know the function is called 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails' .